# See the full details of an Exchange account

Tags: mail.app, accounts, exchange

I set up an Exchange account maybe two years ago and it was a bit tricky to set up since the correct username and server are not in the email address. I am now on macOS 13.6 trying to figure out what settings I used. I can go to **System Settings > Internet Accounts** and see the Exchange account. There is a Details button to update the description and name. However, I can't seem to locate the full details, such as the exact server, domain, and username. That information must be stored somewhere. How do I see it?

Answer (score 3):

While you can see some information in *Mail > Settings > Accounts*, you can access more information in other ways, as explained in  [View email account information in Mail on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/mlhlp1193/mac):

> 1. In the Mail app  on your Mac, in the [Mail sidebar](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/aside/glos87935ffb/16.0/mac/14.0), Control-click a mailbox, then choose Get Account Info.
> 2. In the Account Info window, click the Account pop-up menu, then choose an account.
> 3. Click a tab to view details about the account.
>
>    - *Quota Limits* or *Messages on Server*: Monitor the size of [mailboxes](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/aside/glos8e4eb14f/16.0/mac/14.0) and messages on the mail server. This information can help you manage your messages when you exceed your account storage limits. For example, for an [IMAP account](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mail/aside/glosc623d0f2/16.0/mac/14.0), you can determine which mailbox uses the most space, show the messages, then delete them.
>    - *Summary*: View a summary of **account settings, such as those related to mail servers and security**.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

[image: Screenshot (macOS Sonoma) of the Account Info Summary tab in Mail app]

<sup>Above is a screenshot of the Account Info tab in Mail. Here, I have selected my iCloud account but you should be able to select your Exchange account (or any other account) from the dropdown menu next to "Account:"</sup>